# sending full form data to back end using jquery

Tags: jquery, json

i have a form that is dynamically built. so the number of form elements arr not fixed. I wnat to send whole of $_POSt data from the form using jquery to back end for processing .i cant use jquery form plugin as the jquery version i am using is old.

any other way ?
i tied to do like this

```
$.post('all_include_files/update_save.php',{variable:"<?php echo json_encode($_POST) ?>"},function(data)
{
alert(data);
})
```

but did not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [jQuery.serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/).

It looks like what you're trying to accomplish is similar to:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'all_include_files/update_save.php',
  data: $("form").serialize(),
  success: function(result){ alert(result); }
});
```

Comment: .post() is a shorthand version of .ajax() that assumes some default instructions for you.

Comment: Yes, either implementation should return the same result.  I used .ajax() in my example because I felt like it was easier to illustrate my point.

Comment: but how do i unserialize it at back end ? i did not find specifi function for tht

Comment: Serialize will use the browser's default posting technique.  That is, your server side code can treat the jQuer.serialize()'ed data as if it were a traditional form post.  I'm not sure what the equivalent in PHP is, but in ASP.NET, you would to a Request.Form["inputName"].

Comment: hey we use $_POST in php to get post data . but it did not work .i had to use parse_str($_POST['datas']) where datas is the serialized variable ..

Answer (score 0):

Use [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) (was added in jQuery 1.0)

> The `.serialize()` method creates a text string in standard URL-encoded notation. It operates on a jQuery object representing a set of form elements.

E.g.

```
var data = $('#formid').serialize()
```